# SQLQuery not capturing CRLF for field in generic type

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6, xaf

I have the following code (simplified)

```
 private  List<T> GetList<T>( )
        where T : MyResult, new()
    {
        var db = new MyDbContext();
        var sql = @$"
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        create table #temp ( Description nvarchar(800) )
        insert into #temp (Description) select Description from SomeOtherTable
        select description from #temp 
        where charindex(char(13),description) > 0 and 
              charindex(char(10),description) > 0
        "
        return db.Database.SqlQuery<T>(sql).ToList();
    }


    public override IEnumerable<NonPersistentObjectBase> MyGetData()
    {
        var t = GetType();
        var o = Activator.CreateInstance(t) as MyRec;
        return o.GetList<MyResult>(t).Cast<NonPersistentObjectBase>().ToList();
    }



 public class MyResult : NonPersistentObjectBase {
    [ModelDefault("RowCount", "5")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool HasCrLf => Description.Contains( "\r\n");
    public bool HasCr => Description.Contains("\r"); // returns false
    public bool HasLf => Description.Contains("\n"); // returns true
    
 }
```

The correct MyRec objects are created except that they do not contain "\r\n". That is all the HasCrLf fields are false even when the data contains char(13)+char(10)

EntityFramework is 6.4.4

In management studio I can run

```
select top 10 description, charindex(char(13),description) as PosCR,charindex(char(10),description) as PosLF from someothertable
```

and see that the data does have the CRLF combination.
I note that the structure is varchar not nvarchar

My App is Winforms
I tried SQL Express running on Ubuntu and also on windows.

[Update] 
AlwaysLearning is right. EF seems to be stripping out the carriage return.
I updated the business object class to show.
The problem is not in the sql as I records are returned.

I also added xaf as a tag because I am using it, though it is hard to see how it could be involved.

The issue occurs regardless of whether the #temp Description is varchar or nvarchar

The problem occurs regardless of whether the field is varchar or nvarchar in SomeOtherTable

Comment: Are you 100% sure the data contains those chars?

Comment: Are you running this on Linux or macOS? Is it possible that EF6 is "helping" you by converting the `\r\n` sequence to just `\n`? (I wouldn't expect it to, but who knows?)

Comment: Thank you. I updated the question. EF seems to be "helping"